# How to regex match text with different endings?

Tags: php, html, regex

This is what I have at the moment.

```
<h2>Information</h2>\n  +<p>(.*)<br />|</p>
                  ^ that is a tab space, didn't know if there was
 a better way to represent one or more (it seems to work)
```

Im trying to match the 'bla bla.' text, but my current regex doesn't quite work, it will match most of the line, but I want it to match the first

```
<h2>Information</h2>
    <p>bla bla.<br /><br /><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a><br />
```

or

```
<h2>Information</h2>
    <p>bla bla.</p> other code...
```

Oh and my php code:

```
    preg_match('#h2>Information</h2>\n  +<p>(.*)<br />|</p>#', $result, $postMessage);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use regex to parse HTML. PHP provides [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) that can be used for this purpose.

Having said that you have some errors in your regular expression:

- You need parentheses around the alternation.
- You need lazy modifiers.
- You can't type 'header' to match 'Information'.

With these changes it would look like this:

```
<h2>.*?</h2>\n\t+<p>.*?(<br />|</p>)
```

Your regular expression is also very fragile. For example, if the input contains spaces instead of tabs or the line ending is Windows-style, your regular expression will fail. Using a proper HTML parser will give a much more robust solution.

Comment: +1 for don't use regex. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags for further details.

Comment: Cheers, and I will look into that DOMDocument as I can't say I like using regex, it was just all I knew that cold do it.

Comment: Oops, that header thing was a typo.

Comment: It's ridiculous how many times this needs to be restated. This same question pops up almost daily.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\s` to match any whitespace character (including spaces, tabs, new-line feeds, etc.), e.g.

```
preg_match('#<h2>header</h2>\s*<p>(.*)<br />|</p>#', $result, $postMessage);
```

But, as already mentioned, do not use regular expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: Ah yeah, might use \s then. Will definitely read up on this DOMDocument thingy that PHP provide.

Answer (score 1):

the .* match should be non greedy (match the minimum of arbitrary characters instead of the maxium), that is (.*?) i guess in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Try making your match `non-greedy` by using `(.*?)` in place of `(.*)`